# What is the recommended tool to start CI/CD for Salesforce development?

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, git, cicd

I'm new to this subject, but trying to start on the right foot.
What are the recommended tools to start CI/CD for Salesforce development source version control and SFDX context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends...

In my *opinion* the simplest approach *if you are using GitHub* is to use [GitHub Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/01/using-salesforce-dx-with-github-actions). (This is missing from the page Phil linked to.) This avoids subscribing to and sorting out authentication for and learning about another system. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). We've been using this successfully for a while now.

I presume this same benefit comes from using Bitbucket Pipelines if you are using Bitbucket for Git.

Adding an additional system for CI can make sense if you have specific requirements that such a system satisfies.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I already started learning about managing CI/CD with git actions as you suggested and it makes sense: unlocked packages with scratch orgs but again KISS all the way

Answer (score 3):

**WARNING**: References to any specific technology is not a recommendation.

Salesforce covers various common options in their [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci.htm), including Jenkins and Travis CI.

We happen to use Bitbucket as our repository and implemented CI/CD using [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines/). The latter uses a Docker image we set up that includes the sfdx CLI, with yaml scripting to perform the various sfdx commands in a controlled and scripted manner (we also invoke our LWC jest tests here too).

There are various third-party options such as [GearSet](https://gearset.com/landing/ppc/devops-2), [Copado](https://www.copado.com) and [AutoRabit](https://www.autorabit.com/products/automated-release-management) amongst others as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PhilW